# Mobile apps created using kendo ui

Tags: jquery-mobile, kendo-mobile

I'm evaluating various html 5 mobile frameworks. Kendo UI mobile is one of most promising frameworks i saw in the evaluation. It is primarily because of its nice set of examples.

But i didn't find enough information about the apps which are created using kendo ui mobile. I tried their success stories but i found only [Paylocity](http://www.telerik.com/company/success-stories/details/paylocity-uses-telerik-to-develop-cross-platform-self-service-payroll-app-in-under-six-months) which requires login for testing it out. But i don't have any.

Do you know any complex app which is created using kendo ui mobile. Which is available in app store and play store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a showcase now.  Typing additional characters to make this a legit SO answer.

http://www.telerik.com/platform/showcases

Answer (score 0):

You could use this app which is developed using kendo ui

https://play.google.com/store/search?q=gargash&c=apps